# Python Validate to only allow Numbers and 2 Decimals

Tags: python, django

was wondering if anyone could help me to validate my entries to only allow numeric values with two decimal places.

Here is the models.py:

```
class Records(models.Model):
    capital = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    years = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this on the Model or in a Form.

Django has a [built-in validator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/validators/#decimalvalidator) for just this case:

```
from django.core.validators import DecimalValidator
...
# In the model:
capital = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, validators=[DecimalValidator])

# Or in a Form:
capital = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, validators=[DecimalValidator])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have defined the models quite well. To validate the model, you can use the clean_fields() or clean() methods of the Django Model class. You can read more about django model validation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean_fields)

Comment: hey thanks for your reply, is it correct that I do it in models.py ? Cause in the views.py is where all the calculations get done and so on, the decimals are sorted now all I want is to only allow Numbers for input in all fields.

Answer (score 0):

You could write and add custom validator to your fields

> [Django validators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/validators/)